# Correct URLs in multipage app

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, gruntjs

I have a multiple page backbone app based off of this example: https://github.com/asciidisco/grunt-requirejs/tree/master/examples/multipage-shim and it is working fine for the base url. The problem comes when I navigate to a page that is no longer at the root of the domain.

The directory structure looks like this:

```
scripts
  ├── app
  │   ├── controller
  │   │   ├── Base.js
  │   │   ├── c1.js
  │   │   └── c2.js
  │   ├── lib.js
  │   ├── main1.js
  │   ├── main2.js
  │   ├── model
  │   │   ├── Base.js
  │   │   ├── m1.js
  │   │   └── m2.js
  ├── common.js
  ├── page1.js
  └── page2.js
```

So, e.g. if I navigate to `http://localhost/`, everything loads correctly with the following script tag:

```
    <script data-main="/scripts/page1"  src="/path/to/require.js">
```

(This loads page1, which in turn loads common.js and main1.js).

However, if I navigate to `http://localhost/another/url/`, then the same script tag successfully loads page1.js and common.js, however when it tries to load main1.js, I get a 404, because it is loading from a relative URL (trying to load `http://localhost/another/url/scripts/app/main1.js`.

My `baseUrl` is set to `'scripts'`, and I am building using grunt (https://github.com/asciidisco/grunt-requirejs).

The contents of page1.js is just this:

```
//Load common code that includes config, then load the app logic for this page.
require(['./common'], function (common) {
    require(['app/main1']);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone stumbling upon this question, I found this workaround:

require.js supports having two separate `baseUrl` parameters, one for the build step, and one to be used by the deployed javascript.

By setting build `baseUrl: 'scripts'` and the deployed `baseUrl: '/scripts'` I was able to ensure that require always tries to fetch scripts from the root on the server.